# Asincronismo en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asincronismo

Tengo problema con mi código. No se ejecuta en orden, al hacer un `getJSON` `request` se tarda un poco.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var channels = ['ESL_SC2', 'OgamingSC2', 'cretetion', 'freecodecamp', 'storbeck', 'habathcx', 'RobotCaleb', 'noobs2ninjas'];
  getChannelsNames();

  function getChannelsNames(){
    var myHtml = '', status = 'Offline';

    channels.forEach(function(channel, callback){
      $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/' + channel, function(json){
        status = onlineStatus(json);
        myHtml += infoChannels(channel, status);
      }).fail(function(){
        console.log('Error');
        myHtml += infoChannels(channel, status);
      });
    });
    $('.channels').html(myHtml);
  }

  function onlineStatus(json){
    if(json.stream){
      return json.stream.game;
    } else {
      return 'Offline';
    }
  }

  function infoChannels(channel, status){
    return "<div class='row'><div class='col-12 col-md-4 bg-info'>" + channel + "</div><div class='col-12 col-md-8 bg-primary text-center'>" + status + "</div></div>";
  }
});
```

En esta parte `$('.channels').html(myHtml);` no hace lo que debería hacer porque la variable `myHtml` tendría que contener algo que se le debería de asignar adentro de `getJSON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como está dentro de un `forEach` la petición [$.getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) lo correcto sería añadir el `html` cuando se obtenga el `success`*(done)*  de la petición,  si no al final la variable posiblemente esté vacía o no contenga todos los datos.
Además no seteamos el `HTML` directamente si no que insertamos contenido a lo que ya existe este con [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var channels = ['ESL_SC2', 'OgamingSC2', 'cretetion', 'freecodecamp', 'storbeck', 'habathcx', 'RobotCaleb', 'noobs2ninjas'];
  getChannelsNames();

  function getChannelsNames(){
    var myHtml = '', status = 'Offline';

    channels.forEach(function(channel, callback){
      var jqxhr = $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/' + channel, function(){
        
        }).done(function(json) {
          myHtml = ''; //seteamos el html a añadir
          status = onlineStatus(json);
          myHtml += infoChannels(channel, status);
          $('.channels').append(myHtml);//añadimos al div con clase channels
        })
      .fail(function(){
        console.log('Error');
        myHtml += infoChannels(channel, status);
      });
    });
    
  }

  function onlineStatus(json){
    if(json.stream){
      return json.stream.game;
    } else {
      return 'Offline';
    }
  }

  function infoChannels(channel, status){
    return "<div class='row'><div class='col-12 col-md-4 bg-info'>" + channel + "</div><div class='col-12 col-md-8 bg-primary text-center'>" + status + "</div></div>";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<div class="channels">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.